# Find the roots of a list of derivatives

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, procedural-programming

I want to be able to take a polynomial and take the 1st 5 derivatives, then add at least one root of each derivative to a list using a loop. However, each attempt I try only ends up outputting the roots of the 5th derivative, not the rest. So far I have:

```
rootderivs[n_]:=( 
p[x_]:= x^8-3x^5+x-1;
rootlist={};
Do[ 
AppendTo[rootlist, NSolve[D[p[x],{x,n}]==0]],1];
Print[rootlist])
```

Which gives an ouput of :

```
rootderivs[5]
{{{x->-0.188487-0.326469 I},{x->-0.188487+0.326469 I},{x->0.376974}}}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Your Do loop only loops one time because you defined: Do[..,1] I think that is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
Table[D[x^8 - 3 x^5 + x - 1, {x, n}], {n, 1, 8}]
(* {1 - 15 x^4 + 8 x^7, -60 x^3 + 56 x^6, -180 x^2 + 336 x^5, -360 x + 
  1680 x^4, -360 + 6720 x^3, 20160 x^2, 40320 x, 40320} *)
```

```
Table[NSolve[D[x^8 - 3 x^5 + x - 1, {x, n}] == 0, x], {n, 1, 8}]

(* {{{x -> -0.628102 - 1.06836 I}, {x -> -0.628102 + 
     1.06836 I}, {x -> -0.5}, {x -> 0.00877753 - 0.507295 I}, {x -> 
    0.00877753 + 0.507295 I}, {x -> 0.518012}, {x -> 
    1.22064}}, {{x -> -0.511632 - 0.886173 I}, {x -> -0.511632 + 
     0.886173 I}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 
    1.02326}}, {{x -> -0.406083 - 0.703356 I}, {x -> -0.406083 + 
     0.703356 I}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 
    0.812165}}, {{x -> -0.299204 - 0.518237 I}, {x -> -0.299204 + 
     0.518237 I}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 
    0.598408}}, {{x -> -0.188487 - 0.326469 I}, {x -> -0.188487 + 
     0.326469 I}, {x -> 0.376974}}, {{x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.}}, {{x -> 
    0.}}, {}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

p[x_] := x^8 - 3 x^5 + x - 1
```

For the real roots

```
Table[NSolve[D[p[x], {x, n}] == 0, x, Reals] // Union, {n, 5}] // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[
   Tooltip[D[p[x], {x, n}], Derivative[n]["p"][x]],
   {n, 5}],
 {x, -0.6, 1.25},
 PlotRange -> 10,
 PlotLegends -> Table[Derivative[n]["p"][x], {n, 5}],
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]